# read an xml file with complex struct asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm beginner on asp.net and  I want to read red data from an xml file with
complex structure. It works when structures are simple.

This is my Xml file

```
<Flights>
  <Flight>
    <Content>gds</Content>
    <Currency>MAD</Currency>
    <Amount>11777</Amount>
    <Duration>02h30m</Duration>
    <Stops>0</Stops>
    <OfficeId>OOOO01</OfficeId>
    <Itineraries>
      <Itinerary>
        <Ref>1</Ref>
        <Duration>02h30m</Duration>
        <Stops>0</Stops>
        <AvailableSeats>7</AvailableSeats>
      </Itinerary>
    </Itineraries>
  </Flight>
</Flights>
```

I already extract models

```
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("Flights"), XmlType("Flights")]  
    public class Flights
    {


        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public string Duration { get; set; }
        public int Stops { get; set; }
        public string OfficeId{ get; set; }
        public List< Itineraries> Itinerary { get; set; }


    }





  [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("Itineraries"), XmlType("Itineraries")]
   public class Itineraries
    {
        public string Ref { get; set; }
        public string Duration { get; set; }
        public string Stops { get; set; }
        public string AvailableSeats { get; set; }



    }
```

I have also an xml reader that read only simple Attributes

```
  public List<Flights> RetrunListOfProducts()
           {
               string xmlData = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/FlightData.xml");//Path of the xml script  
               DataSet ds = new DataSet();//Using dataset to read xml file  
               ds.ReadXml(xmlData);
               var flights = new List<Flights>();

               flights = (from rows in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                           select new Flights
                           {
                               //Convert row to int  
                               Content = rows[0].ToString(),
                               Currency = rows[1].ToString(),
                               Amount = Convert.ToInt32(rows[2].ToString()),
                               Duration = rows[3].ToString(),
                               Stops = Convert.ToInt32(rows[4].ToString()),
                               OfficeId = rows[5].ToString(),

                               itinerary <--- How do I read this part?


                           }).ToList();
return flights;
}
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: What is your problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Why are you using DataSet? Try XmlSerializer as suggested below by J.C or parse the file with XmlDocument or XDocument.

Answer (score 0):

Will you consider using [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.100).aspx) to deserialize your data? It works like you load the XML file into an object.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(xmlData);
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Flight));
Flights f = xs.Deserialize(sr) as Flight;
```

However, you may need some modification in your Flight type

1. You should use array instead of List<>
2. Add attribute [XmlArray("Name")] and [XmlArrayItem("Name")] in your array type members.

For example

```
[XmlArray("Itineraries")]
[XmlArrayItem("Itinerary")]
public Itinerary[] Itinerary;
```